# Android Geocoder Returns State Route xx, Can It Return The Actual Street Name?

Tags: android, geocoding

I'm using Android's Geocoder to get street and suburb for my App, however on some roads, it will return State Route 60 for example, rather than the actual road name.

I'm in Western Australia if that makes any difference.

Is there a way around that ?
Or will I have to guess the street based on latitude and longitude ?

And in the same vein - the Geocoder returns streets as "St" and Roads as "Rd".
I can't find a default way of expanding that. If there is one, I would love to know about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up changing the amount of addresses that the `getFromLocation` method returned to 2, and then adding logic in to detect when the first address is returned contained State Route.
When the first address returned State Route, it would use the second returned address instead.